# Excel Conditional Formatting only on rows that contain x

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-formatting

I've got a pretty big generated excel file with a lot of data.

I want to color using conditional formatting all cells that are on the row containing string "delta" and are > 0.3

Object1i23___0.99___59.03___-11.48___-43.26____0.48___1
Object2i16___0.99___59.11___-10.6____-43______1.29___1
delta________0______0.08_____0.88____0.26____0.8____0

So in this case it would color on 3rd row, the cells with 0.88 and 0.8

I tried looking everywhere at advanced conditional formatting and cannot find anything. Is this possible?

NOTE: Excel 2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a conditional formatting rule for D:I based on the following formula,

```
=and($c1="delta", d1>0.3)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. First line is actually the C column in the excel. I tried this formula but afterwards it changed it to   ="and($c1=""delta""; d1>0.3)"   and it still doesn't work.

NOTE: I tried with =and($c1="delta"; d1>0.3) and it does not allow me to hit ok in the "Edit formatting rule" window.

This is Excel 2013

Comment: @AndreiM.   you have to use a comma `,` not `;` in between the function before d1

Comment: i tried that but it seems like formulae work like this in this office version? at least in the suggestion they work like this

=IF (logical_test; [value_if_true]; [value_if_false])

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/83AMjqq.jpg

sorry for the shitty screenshot, imgur upload is blocked @ work

Answer (score 0):

Conditional Formatting based on formula:

=AND($C1="delta";D1>0,3)

applied on all cells starting at D1 which you want to color.

Problem was that i was exporting from matlab as strings (because of some data type problem in excel) and the formula was not recognizing the second condition.

I don't know why on the internet the formulas have ',' but my excel works with ';' inside the formula.

Comment: The reason for "," vs ";" is the language setup on your computer (and your excel workbook). Several European countries uses ";" as a **delimiter** sign in excel (I used it too), while the US metric system uses "," as a delimiter.
So all formulas that uses "," you can change to ";" and they will work for you :)